# In JavaScript Is it better to throw an exception first then return the value or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, exception, error-handling, return

Let's say `value` argument may be `string` or `null`

```
function doSomething1(value) {
  if (value) {
    // do something
  }

  throw new Error("No value provided");
}

function doSomething2(value) {
  if (!value) {
    throw new Error("No value provided");
  }

  // do something
}
```

In that case, I want to check the `value` and throw an error if it's null.

*Question:* Is there any technical difference in terms of performance or memory usage between the functions `doSomething1` and `doSomething2` considering that `// do something` part may be small or huge? Will the order of exception throwing influence the performance at any level at all or is it 100% identical use cases?

Comment: Why would there be a difference in performance? In both cases you'd be executing the exact same code. Wither the `if` triggers or not wouldn't make a difference - code path would be the same in either case.

Comment: @VLAZ My colleagues are convincing me that I should prefer the second case rather than the first during the code review, but no one seems to have an explanation for why it is better.

Comment: Code readability is very subjective, I agree with your colleagues, that the second example makes it clear right from the start that no code runs unless `value` is truthy.

Comment: @Slava.In [early exit style](https://medium.com/swlh/return-early-pattern-3d18a41bba8) has nothing to do with performance, everything to do with readablity

Comment: Your main code will have one less level of indent in the second case.  As a general rule, the less indentation, the cleaner the code.  Many levels of indentation often indicate that the code should be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no difference in terms of runtime:

In both cases, if `value` is `null`, you have one boolean check and an error throw, otherwise you have one check and the execution of the `// do something` block.

The difference is purely code style. I personally prefer the second one as it reduces the indent level by one on `// do something`, and puts error handling all in one place (whereas in the first one, you have the check at the beginning of the method and the throw at the end).